# Harry Potter fanfic where abused Harry works at potion store keeping his identity secret

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

Looking for a Harry Potter fan fiction that contains the following elements:

- Harry was abused/mistreated so he runs away
- I believe this was pre-Hogwarts
- Harry keeps his identity a secret, either through glamor, goblin help, or metamorphagus powers
- Harry gets a job brewing and learning potions at Diagon Alley in a potion store/apothecary
- Harry lives at the potion store with the owner. The owner teaches him, and Harry helps brew for the store
- Harry has nightmares while living there
- Snape goes to visit his friend, the store owner, who has more free time with Harry helping
- The store owner seeks Snape's help to help Harry (identity not known)
- Snape and Harry bond
- Harry leaves secretly before his Hogwarts letter would come, Snape is sad
- Harry goes to Hogwarts but does not reveal himself to Snape
- At Hogwarts, Harry sends and receives letters from the store owner and Snape while still keeping his identity a secret.
- Snape thinks Harry is bad at portions because he tries to experiment like they did over the summer but the potions fail/don’t look like what they were making. Harry is confused why Snape is mad about failed experimentation.

I do not remember what happens after this part. I do not believe the story was completed.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?

Comment: Maybe the same one as https://www.reddit.com/r/HPfanfiction/comments/iaqt9g/harry_discovers_and_works_in_a_potionapothecary/

Comment: http://www.potionsandsnitches.org/fanfiction/viewstory.php?sid=3498 is similar.

Comment: I don't know if you're still around, but if you are, you can accept an answer by clocking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like "[And Still Can't Stop Hoping](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/2964792/1/And-Still-Can-t-Stop-Hoping)" by Samantha Aswad.

The protagonist is named Lucas Harry Potter, and has an older brother, Jonathan, who is the heir to the Potter name. Lily died in childbirth with Lucas, and James, who can't help but resent Lucas for "killing his mother", stays overlong at the pub, drowning his sorrows, the night Voldemort shows up and kills himself trying to curse Lucas, and in fact, no one is aware that Lucas is the "boy who lived", believing that Neville is the prophesied child. James moves from emotional neglect to physical abuse, and eventually ships Harry off to the Dursleys, who abuse him in a manner closer to the books until he runs away and goes to the potion shop, where indeed Snape shows up.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by editing it to specify the ways in which this matches the fanfic described in the question, and any ways in which it doesn't.